# How to change console codepage?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, charset, code-page

How can I change codepage in console (Ctrl+Alt+Fn, not in terminal) to UTF8?
I'm using ukrainian locale by default, so most programs have cyrillic symbols in their output, but they're displayed incorrect, while in gui terminal everything is OK.

```
# locale
LANG=uk_UA.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="uk_UA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

# cat /etc/locale.gen | grep -v [#]
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8
uk_UA.UTF-8 UTF-8

# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
uk_UA.utf8
```

Comment: @techie007 that answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: "Doesn't work for you" in what way? What did you try exactly? What were the results?

Comment: @techie07 I've tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` from that answer too. The results are same: ukrainian characters are still displayed incorrectly in tty.

Comment: To get *displaying* correct you'll also want to have proper fonts/conversion tables loaded; for Cyrillic languages, the most simple way to achieve this is probably to install and configure the [`console-cyrillic`](https://packages.debian.org/console-cyrillic) package.